# How to train tesseract and how to recognize multiple columns

Tags: ocr, multiple-columns, tesseract

I have the task of taking a PDF with images to a txt or csv file to store at a database. I am trying to use OCR on images like the one attached.

The results are as poor as the following:

```
`20—0
¿ ABÚEADD LDIDI ALBARH, JDSE
AHTÚHIÚ
—- EnlúndeLarreájzegm25- Sºt] . . . . . 944 355019
: ABDGADD 5E'I'IEH ÁLUAREI 5EUERIHD`
```

Of special importance is the phone number (944 355019), it seems close to correct but it still has wrong digits which makes the whole thing useless.

After much reading I still do not know how to train tesseract. I am following [this instructions](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Training-Tesseract) among others, which leads me with doubts such as:

1. It talks about getting a sample of the fonts to train. I have an image, so how do I get the exact font to somehow generate the training data?
2. More often than not I get the text moved from where you would expect to find it. I just read that that is because tesseract does OCR on a per column basis (and then I read it does not so I am confused). So, which one is it, and how make it to write it horizontally?

[image: example]